# What is a good language with good support for matrix calc and a scripting interface?

Tags: programming-languages, linear-algebra

I need to brush up some linear algebra concepts and i basically need to dedicated a big part of my work to *pure math* but i also need to use and create some tools like a window or a 3D object with OpenGL to make data visualization easier.

What language you will suggest, that it's oriented to scripting, requires little to no times to build and run things, easy to debug and has a really good support to the math world?

I honestly think that Python is a good choice, but i found that having 2 major versions of the same language at the same time it's not a good thing, it's hard to find a reliable source for the version of choice and most people who write about Python forget to specify what is the version that they are talking about. The Python docs around the internet are really *polluted* but the language is probably good enough for me.

One thing that i found not so good about Python is the speed, if I try to do something that needs to be done in something like a fraction of second, python is simply not that fast compared to compiled languages like C++; but I have to say that Python is probably the only one language that i know that offers native support for complex numbers.

I also would like to know about other possible choice other than Python or your idea about Python.

Short version: I need to do linear algebra and I need to do this with the aid of standard technologies to get information from this calcs.

Comment: Mathematica is probably what you want. ...  Hmm, not free or cheap, even for students though.

Comment: People don't bother to specify Python versions because, most of the time, it doesn't matter. 90% of the language remained unchanged by Python 3, and a lot of libraries support both 2.x and 3.x, so Python expertise transfers between both versions easily.

Comment: MATLAB is a popular favourite for engineers and researchers, but it's not free.

Comment: i think that instead of using Matlab or Mathematica, i can just go for Octave or some other good opensource alternative, i just need to do basic stuff but with an _handy_ interface. But this are all environments/IDE, and i think that they will not be that good in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python with NumPy is a good choice for matrix math. NumPy is a reasonably high-performance matrix library, and it works well with Python and many other standard packages (e.g. PyOpenGL, Python Imaging Library, SciPy, matplotlib, etc.).

Comment: Python 3 or Python 2.x ? Where i can get reliable docs about Python and the math ?

Comment: http://docs.python.org does a good job with the basics (assuming you kind of already know Python); http://docs.scipy.org documents NumPy. If you're looking for a good tutorial, http://docs.python.org/tutorial/ and http://www.learnpython.org/ are pretty good IMO.

Comment: @Ken NumPy supports both Python 2 and Python 3. Reliable documentation is everywhere! The authoritative option for core language and standard library is http://docs.python.org/ while third party packages (at least the decent ones) have a link on their [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) page.

Comment: @delnan what a funny language, i need to know how to use the PyPI ... by the way, everywhere it's not really a good choice, i will go for the docs subdomain.

Comment: @nneonneo i don't think that Python is hard to grasp, i just don't get what docs i'm supposed to read when starting this considering this fork in 2 main versions.

Comment: @Ken No, you just need to know where to find packages. As in any ecosystem. Except that the Python ecosystem has a centralized solution used by almost every library, unlike in some other ecosystems. Packaging sucks at times, but in this regard it works quite well.